# Como colocar o conteúdo de um Ajax Post (resposta recebida após o post) em uma popup? (post enviado através de uma extensão)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão

Oi. Preciso colocar a resposta de um ajax post em uma popup usando javascript. Alguém tem ideia? é possível fazer isso?  Funciona assim: Ao fazer o post (variavel.send(...);), ele mostraria o conteúdo de resposta (o que volta do servidor após processar os dados) em uma nova pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Cara tem várias formas de fazer isso. É só vc pegar o callback da requisição.
Veja abaixo um exemplo usando Asp Net MVC:

Código que você vai colocar em sua view com a requisição ajax.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "Home/Index", //Endereço do controller / action
   contentType: "application/json" //Irá retornar um json no callback,
   success: function(data){ //Se ocorrer tudo certo com a requisição
       //Aqui você trabalha o resultado retornado pelo servidor
       //Como retornou um json vc pode acessar as propridades através data.propriedade
       alert('Resultado do servidor' + data.retorno);
   }
});
```

No o controller ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    //declarando um tipo para retornar para view (classe logo abaixo)
    var retorno = new ClasseA(){
        Id = 1,
        retorno = 'retorno'
    };
    return Json(retorno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}

public class ClasseA{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string retorno { get; set;}
}
```